# Attribute prediction with CNN and cross entropy loss (negative values for absent attributes)

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am building a neural net (CNN) which predict 100 attributes of an image. The training data is as follows-

`image_name image_attributes`

`img/img001.jpg -1, 1, -1 , 1, 0 .......-1 , 1`

So the attributes which are present have value `1`, and `-1` if that attribute is not present and `0` if unknown. I am using Tensorflow and defining my loss as -

`loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))`

My question is if I minimize this loss, sometimes it has negative values due to `-1` representation of absence of some attributes and my optimization algorithm will minimize the already negative loss. Isn't it a divergence?

Is it correct to minimize this loss or should I use mod function to have only positive losses?

Comment: soft max convert your result into a probability of the range between 0 and 1. and the by using cross entropy your penalizing the answer if it is not one in the chosen class. so you should see your result as x,y,z which one is having the higher probability to obe choosing and penalize on the confidence

Comment: You should use one-hot-encoding for your classes. This means encoding the labels into a (samples, 3) form of 0 and 1 depending on which class this sample belongs to.

Comment: @ThomasPinetz These are attributes i.e. non exclusive classes. So how would one hot encoding work? and what about unknown attributes which are represented by '0'

Comment: you still have 3 classes. 1 0 0 would be unknown. 0 1 0 would be false and 0 0 1 would be true.

Comment: really? Who has a problem with the question to downvote? Care to explain please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to make it clear you should see your result out of the classifier as three nodes having their result whatever it is. which they are (y0,y1,y2) and then by applying softmax on these results you'll have a new values representing the answer in a probability range between 0 and 1

[image]

so let's say you have a result of this form [1,−2,0] by applying the softmax you'll have  [0.7,0.04,0.26]

```
p_y_given_x = softmax(y_given_x)
```

and then by applyinng argmax you can define which class is predicted based on the highest probability result

```
y_prediction = argmax(p_y_given_x)
```

which mean in our case [1,0,0]

now what you should do is to take the number of the predicted class based on your data attribution.

but first let's agree on one thing

- present: class 0
- not present: class 1
- un known: class 2

let's say your object is not present in the image so you should take the value of the second object and apply logliklihood

```
-log(p_y_given_x[y])
```

which is the second one 0.04 and penalize the system by back propagating the error in this manner.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I get what you are explaining. I am worried about the negative total-loss which I am seeing. Softmax will convert each attribute value into probabilities. How would I calculate cross entropy loss? and isn't the loss should always be positive value?

Comment: your softmax as I explained will convert your result to be in the range 0 and 1 which is positive. if it answered your question mark it as answer plz

Comment: I get that it will convert my result in 0-1 but the ground truth is not in range of 0-1 it is,  -1,0,-1 and calculating cross entropy loss  sumofall (- Yi*ln(1/Pi)) may give negative value.

Comment: I also explained in the details that you have to convert you GT into class of present on the range (y0,y1,y2) where one exist represent the class. so where you are applying the log is just over the prediction out of the softmax

Comment: Just one more clarification, since I have 100 attributes to predict for an image and three classifier for each attribute means I should have 300 outputs? and then group them in bundle of three [ y0, y1, y2] [y3, y4, y5] ..[ ]  for each attribute?

Comment: if each classifier trained individually the 100 classes should belong to the classifier itself. then you can another method succh as voting or grouping to decide on which to take.

Comment: each classifier classify 'each' attribute into 3 classes - present. absent, unknown. Didn't get how voting will work?

Comment: Why do u need three classifiers?

Comment: 3 classifier for each attribute. ( present, absent and unknown) This is what you explained above. You are calling it class 0 , class 1, class 2.

Comment: these are classes not classifiers. you miss some foundation in theory I'd advice you to start from here http://cs231n.github.io/

Comment: not really, your comments are confusing. Anyways thanks for helping out mate. appreciate it :). I would still mark it as correct answer. will publish my results based on my benchmarking. I am testing out the effect of different encodings of data.

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing your range to [0, 1], with near 0 being not present, near 1 being present, and unknown being any value that doesn't pass a threshold.

You're trying to get a scalar value to represent two dimensions: presence of the attribute and confidence in prediction.

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but I am just benchmarking a method to predict the unknown explicitly. Last resort is simple one hot encoding and thresholds based on probabilities.

Comment: It is exactly the same if you use [0, 1], where 0.5 is the middle value...

Comment: okay! This is what I am experimenting upon. So will revert back with the results. Thank you :)